# Iterate over JSON array using bash jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'd like to iterate over an array inside a JSON file by index using bash jq, and get for example only the name from each object inside that array:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "item1",
      "year": "2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "item2",
      "year": "2020"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve something like this?

```
item1name=`jq '.items'<???????> object.json | sed "s/\"//g"`
```

Comment: `jq` is not part of `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
jq -r '.items[] | .name' object.json
```

where `-r` option is used to remove double quotes wrapping up the name values.

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OCnuLPnBdy)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way that I can save this array of names which I can then use dynamically by using an index of somehow?

Comment: After Googling for Bash arrays, I came across this approach to iterate over arrays:

`for i in ${!names[@]}; do
  printf "${names[$i]}"
  printf "\n"
done`

Comment: Use the bash [`readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-readarray) command to capture the lines of output from jq into a bash array. `readarray -t names < <(jq -r ...)`